# Append an integer to std::wstring gives an error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wstring

ALL,

I'm using MSVC 2010 and have a problem with the subject.

Using following code:

```
int GetValue() {return m_int;};

std::wstring temp += std::to_wstring( GetValue() );
```

gives an error:

```
ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(771): could be 'std::wstring std::to_wstring(long double)'
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(762): or       'std::wstring std::to_wstring(_ULonglong)'
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(753): or       'std::wstring std::to_wstring(_Longlong)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
```

Using following code:

```
ostringstream ostr;
ostr << GetValue();
std::wstring temp += ostr.str();
```

gives following error:

```
error C2679: binary '+=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Where I am wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first case is a compiler / standard library bug; that should work

Comment: This is probably not a compiler/library bug.  There are reasons for not having implicit conversions between ASCII character conversion to wide character conversion. Or a string of *narrow* characters to a string of *wide* characters.

Comment: If you're trying to append to an existing string, why do you have the type declaration on that line? That declares a new variable.

Comment: You should try a newer version of VC++.  Since `std::to_wstring` was added in C++11, it's no surprise that VC2010 support is incomplete.

Comment: @BenVoigt, an autocompletion does show his function inside IDE.

Comment: @Igor: But only with a fraction of the overloads it should come with.  It's not totally missing, but incomplete.

Comment: `std::to_wstring()` is a C++11 thing, and VS10 doesn't exactly have stellar C++11 support. My bet is that upgrading to a newer version of VS will resolve that particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular `std::ostringstream` is not wide.  The `wstring` would like to be assigned a wide string.

You'll need [`std::wostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a compound assignment in a variable declaration.

The `=` introducing an initializer is not an assignment operator, it is part of the grammar for declarations.  You cannot substitute some seemingly-related token.

If you want to initialize a variable, use simple `=`:

```
std::wstring temp = std::to_wstring( GetValue() );
```

If you want to do compound assignment, do it in a separate statement subsequent to the declaration:

```
std::wstring temp;
temp += std::to_wstring( GetValue() );
```